# How can I input the cents (like for currency) symbol on the axis of a graph in R?

Tags: r

I am struggling to find the way to display the cent currency symbol in R. Any ideas?

I am trying to display the cents symbol on the axis of a graph and the title for something on a R Shiny dashboard. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add the code you have? It may very well depend on what you're doing exactly. Have you tried plotting `"\u00A2"`?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Do you mean this symbol "¢"? You can use the unicode value to put it in a variable like a regular character: `x <- "\U00A2"`

Comment: `plot(c(1,2,3), xlab="¢", ylab="¢", main="¢")`